# How to free skb buffer without freeing data pointer pointed by it?

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, network-programming, buffer

I have a situation where i have to free only `skb` structure itself but not data pointer. I'm reusing data pointer in my driver. Please note that, `skb` is not a clone.

Comment: You may want to post some sort of code...

Comment: You may store `->head` field of `skb` somewhere and set the field to NULL before calling `kfree_skb`. Note, that you is allowed do that only when there is no other users of this `skb` instance. When data becomes unneded, call `kfree()` for stored pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
skb->cloned = 1;
atomic_inc(&(skb_shinfo(skb)->dataref));

give_skb_to_function_that_might_free_it(skb);
```

Now `kfree_skb` and friends will think another socket buffer has a reference on the data and free only the `struct sk_buff`. Don't forget to free the data yourself later on though!

EDIT: Alternatively, set `skb->head = NULL` inside the SKB's `.destructor`...